# Looping over array of type float with interval of float (NDVI) using Python?

Tags: python, ndvi

I am stuck with my Python Script. The case is, I have an array of floating numbers from 0 to 1 (NDVI values). I want to loop over my array with an interval/step of every 0.025. Every interval/step I have to calculate something a+(b*element in the loop).

```
vNdvi = one dimensional array of NDVI values coming from a MODIS image

rNdvi = vNdvi[np.logical_and(vNdvi>=0.3, vNdvi<0.8)]

rNdvi.sort()
```

Comment: if your values are 0 to 1 by 0.025 that's 40 increments.. create a range of 40 for your steps then search through until you find the value you want, add 0.025 to the expected value and search again.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the good suggestion. Will definitely try it. Never thought of it, my mind was locked up in range function.